# oracle 11g alternative for fetch first?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-limit

this code worked fine in the Oracle live sql but when i put it on the server im getting a SQL command not properly ended was wondering if its because its different oracle versions, the server is in oracle11g

```
SELECT g.GID, g.Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM VisitN v JOIN
     GuestN g
     ON v.GID = g.GID
GROUP BY g.GID, g.Name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

thank you

Comment: "was wondering if its because its different oracle versions, the server is in oracle11g" -- Yes, `FETCH FIRST ...` is only available from 12c onwards.

Comment: ah ok do u know anyway i can fix it?

Comment: You can use the old strategy that uses `ROWNUM`.

Comment: I tried addding `WHERE rownum <=1;` instead of fetch but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROWNUM`. For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT g.GID, g.Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM VisitN v JOIN
     GuestN g
     ON v.GID = g.GID
  GROUP BY g.GID, g.Name
  order by cnt desc
) x
where rownum = 1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59fd1064405753873776c7f88e2fb95e).

Comment: thanks alot im a bit unfamiliar with this format but it works fine